# Always get "RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found" on Circleci.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, rspec

I'm on Rails 4 and here's my `config/sunspot.yml` --

```
test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
    pid_dir: <%= File.join(::Rails.root, 'tmp', 'pids')%>

  auto_index_callback: after_commit
  auto_remove_callback: after_commit
```

On circleci.com I always get the errors because of solr, so almost none of the tests pass:

```
RSolr::Error::Http:
RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error: Not Found

   URI: http://localhost:8981/solr/test/update?wt=ruby
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Do u have some sorl.xml file in solr folder if yes can u copy it and also as it is a test environment u need to add RAILS_ENV=test in your command for starting solr if it is sunspot solr